# How do I use Javascript to figure out the quantity of 1000s, 100s, 10s, 1s in a number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, math, rounding

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do...

Let's say I have the number 73,284.

The number of **thousands** is 73 (73,284 divided by 1,000).

The number of **hundreds** is 2 (284 divided by 100).

The number of **tens** is 8 (84 divided by 10).

The number of **singles** is 4 (4 is left).

What I need is a Javascript function that would take the number 73,284 and create 4 numbers from it using the criteria above.

So if the number was 73,284, I'd pass that number into the function as a parameter and the function would return an array that looks like this, [73,2,8,4].

I tried to use the Math.round() function. It seemed to work for the thousands, but not necessarily for the hundreds, tens, and singles.

Comment: `I tried to use the Math.round() function. It seemed to work for the thousands, but not necessarily for the hundreds, tens, and singles.`: please show what you tried.

Comment: You probably want floor, not round

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide any attempt you've already made. In doubt, refer to the [ask] section.

Comment: I've modified my solution to include the arithmetic that Jamiec provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by keeping track of how many thousands, hundreds and tens you have and removing these as you go. A little simple arithmetic.

```js
function get(num){
      const thousands = Math.floor(num/1000)
      const hundreds = Math.floor((num-thousands*1000)/100);
      const tens = Math.floor((num-thousands*1000-hundreds*100)/10);
      const units = Math.floor(num-thousands*1000-hundreds*100-tens*10)
      return [
        thousands,
        hundreds,
        tens,
        units
      ]
}

const [th,hu,te,un] = get(73284)

console.log("Thousands=",th);
console.log("Hundreds=",hu);
console.log("Tens=",te);
console.log("Units=",un);
```

Comment: Jamiec, thank you so much! This works. I was missing the "removing these as you go" part in my attempted solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Simple for loop.

```js
const f = (n) => {
    let div = 1000;
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 4 && n; i++, n %= div, div /= 10) {
        result.push(Math.floor(n / div));
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(f(73284));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a combinaison of division with [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) and modulo operator (`%`). The Modulo operator returns the reminder of a division.

Since you will be doing this operation multiple times, this a great opportunity to use recursion. Here is what i've come up with.

First, we need to get how many of a given devider we've got in our input. To do that, you can devide it and ignore the decimal using `Math.floor`.

```js
const input = 73284
const divider = 1000

const amoutOfDividerInInput = input / divider .
// this returns 73.284, we don't want the .284 so we can use Math.floor.

const amountOfDividerInInputWithoutDecimal = Math.floor(amoutOfDividerInInput)

// we print the value
console.log("there are " + amountOfDividerInInputWithoutDecimal + " 1000s in " + input).
```

We, then, need to check what is the reminder of that operation, this is where the modulo operator comes in.

```js
const input = 73284
const divider = 1000

const reminderOfTheDivision = input % divider;
// this gives us 284.
```

We can, then, use this reminder as our new input, and divide the divider by 10, to get how many hundreds are contains in it.

```
// we devide the divider by 10, 
const newDevider = divider / 10;

// we calculate the new amount and reminder
const amoutOfNewDividerInInput = Math.floor(reminderOfTheDivision / newDivider );

const reminderOfTheNewDivision = reminderOfTheDivision % newDivider

// we print the new values
console.log("There are " + amoutOfNewDividerInInput + " 100s in" + input)
```

And this goes on until we are down to the single digit.

As you can see, there are alot of repetition in this code. A good developer is trying to avoid repetition at all cost. To prevent this, we could use a loop or a recursive function. A recursive function is basically a function that call itself. I've choose to use a function, since it's cleaner.

Here is what i've come up with.

```js
function findDividingQuantity(reminder, divider) {
  // if the devider is less than 10, we simply print the reminder.
    if(divider < 10) {
    console.log('and ' + reminder + ' remains.');
    // and we returns to stop the recursion.
    return;
  }
  
  // otherwise, we get the current amount of the divider in the reminder.
  const amount = Math.floor(reminder / divider);
  
  // we then calculate how much is left after the first division,
  // this will become our new reminder.
  const newReminder = reminder % divider;
  
  // knowing how many of the divider there is in the input, we can print it.
  console.log(amount + " " + divider + "s.");
  
  // we call the function again, but with the new reminder
  // and the divider divided by 10
  findDividingQuantity(newReminder, divider / 10)
}

const input = 73284

console.log("In " + input + " there is: ");
// we call the function with the initial divider: 1000.
findDividingQuantity(input, 1000)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example:

```
function test(num) {
  const arr = num.toLocaleString().split(',');
  arr[arr.length-1].toString().split('').map(x=>arr.push(x));
  arr[arr.length-4]=0;
  return arr.map(x=>+x).filter(x=>x);
}
test(1234); // [1,2,3,4]
test(73284); // [73,2,8,4]
```

This also works for the millions, and so forth.
Here, we defined a function that will convert the number to localeString and split the number. Next, we loop through the array and convert every element to numbers.